# Картинка и filestream

Tags: delphi

как сделать тоже самое, только  скачивая гифку с сайта, и загружая картинку через filestream

```
gif:=tgifimage.Create;
gif.LoadFromFile('C:\r.gif');
gif.Animate:=true;
```

как это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Использовать метод [`LoadFromStream()`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/GIFImg_TGIFImage_LoadFromStream@TStream.html). Поменять

```
gif.LoadFromFile('C:\r.gif');
```

на

```
gif.LoadFromStream(someStream);
```